# Getting errors on trying to declare a class in java

Tags: java, class, declare

I got this part of code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Oblig2 {
Meny menyen = new Meny();
public static void main (String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int menyvalg=0;


//Lager filen ved navn Fugleobservasjoner
try{
PrintWriter fil=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Fugleobservasjoner.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Filen finnes ikke");
    } 

//Selve menyen til programmet i en egen klasse.
class Meny {
    int menyvalg=0;
    void Meny() {
System.out.println("====== Meny for registrering av fugleobservasjoner =====");

System.out.println("\n1. Registrer en fugleobservasjon");
    System.out.println("2. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner av en type");
System.out.println("3. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner på ett bestemt sted");
System.out.println("4. Avslutt systemet");

System.out.println("\nVennligst velg et tall: ");
menyvalg = input.nextInt();
    }
}



//Dette er kommandoene for valget som gjøres i menyen.


    }
}
```

But I keep getting errors when compiling as well as a pointer to the part where I declare the Meny-class. It says Cannot find Symbol, which suggest that the variable isn't declared, but how should I do so then? (I am fully aware that there might be better ways of coding this, but this is what I got so far.)
EDIT: Edited the code since I just saw that it didn't include everything... Sorry about that.

Comment: Make sure you are using the appropriate `import` statements.

Comment: Based on the braces in the code you show us, it looks like you're declaring the class inside your main method. You have to declare classes outside of methods.

Comment: @GennaroDeLuca You can declare classes in methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the class `Meny` before attempting to use it, i.e move

```
class Meny {
  ...
}
```

ahead of

```
Meny menyen = new Meny();
```

The order in which classes are defined matters to the compiler. In addition declare the `Scanner` instance final so it can be referenced in the inner class

```
final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: But it depends on the order on which its declared so the compiler wont know anything about it...

Comment: Also the variable `input` must be `final` in order to be used inside of `Meny`.

Comment: @SamYonnou Please explain

Comment: @Makri a non-final variable cannot be referenced inside the method of an inner class

Comment: @Makri Reimus edited his answer to explain it. Basically for a variable to be accessible inside of an anonymous class it must be marked final

Comment: Thanks alot. I moved the declaration down after the class itself and now it compiled atleast. Just got to define the switch-sequence and try calling for the class and be definite that everything works and my day is saved. Thank you! Kinda weird tho, when the book we use declares the class infront of the class itself..

Answer (score -1):

If that's your complete code, then you're missing `}` to close `void Meny()`, another `}` to close `class Meny`, and another `}` to close `main()`. Also, do you have `main()` placed inside a larger class? Java doesn't allow functions to be outside classes.